# how to enable a text box to accept decimal values using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have made a small app using javascript and html.

But recently i encountered a problem with my script.

**Problem :** Input text box are not allowing me to enter  (.)dot/periods i.e decimal values. Example: if i enter a decimal value then it is automatically deleting from my input text box.

What could be reason for this.

I am trying to solve this issue from last 3hrs. But could not found the exact problem. Please check my code and help me to solve this problem.

Relevent code:

```
<table border="0">
    <form name="form_A" onsubmit="return false">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="unit_menu" class="Items" onchange="CalculateUnit(this.form, document.form_B)">
                    <option>
                    ------- Select a Property -------
                                                                    <option>
                    <option>
                    <option>
                    <option>
                    <option>
                </select>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="info" name="unit_input" placeholder="Type to convert" class="textbox" onfocus="CalculateUnit(this.form, document.form_B)" onkeyup="CalculateUnit(this.form, document.form_B)"></td>

        </tr>
    </form>
    <form name="form_B" onsubmit="return false">
        <tr>

            <td>
                <select name="unit_menu" class="Items" onchange="valuefocus()">
                    <option>
                    ------- Select a Property -------
                    <option>
                    <option>
                    <option>
                    <option>
                    <option>
                </select></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="unit_input" size="20" maxlength="20" placeholder="Type to convert" class="textbox" onfocus="CalculateUnit(this.form, document.form_A)" onkeyup="CalculateUnit(this.form, document.form_A)"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
         function CalculateUnit(sourceForm, targetForm){
            // A simple wrapper function to validate input before making the conversion
            var sourceValue = sourceForm.unit_input.value;

            // First check if the user has given numbers or anything that can be made to
            // one...
            sourceValue = parseFloat(sourceValue);
            if ( !isNaN(sourceValue) || sourceValue == 0){
                // If we can make a valid floating-point number, put it in the
                // text box and convert!
                sourceForm.unit_input.value = sourceValue;
                ConvertFromTo(sourceForm, targetForm);
            } else {
                 //wrong input
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your question

Comment: @JamesMontagne e i updated. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your conversion function is triggered on keyup, so if the users types `3.` it is converted to `3` and put back into the field.

`parseFloat(3.) = 3`

There are several ways to solve this issue.

The simplest would be to not calculate the value on `keyup` but when the user hits `enter` or the field loses focus (`blur`).

Other option would be to check the string value of the field if it ends with a `.` before you parse it and leave it unchanged as long it isn`t a valid number.

Example:

```
function CalculateUnit(sourceForm, targetForm){

    // A simple wrapper function to validate input before making the conversion
    var sourceValue = sourceForm.unit_input.value;

    // First check if the user has given numbers or anything that can be made to
    // one...
    if (!/\.$/.test(sourceValue)) {
        sourceValue = parseFloat(sourceValue);
        if ( !isNaN(sourceValue) || sourceValue == 0){
            // If we can make a valid floating-point number, put it in the
            // text box and convert!
            sourceForm.unit_input.value = sourceValue;
            ConvertFromTo(sourceForm, targetForm);
        } else {
             //wrong input
        }
    } else {
        // sourceValue ends with a '.'
    }
}
```

Comment: so shall i remove `sourceValue = parseFloat(sourceValue);` . This will solve my problem